# Studio backstage shots

Tags: studio-setup

Are there any sites where studio backstage shots can be found? I speak about [this](http://www.flickr.com/photos/89456253@N00/3808195326) and [this](http://www.flickr.com/photos/89456253@N00/2471133513). Not about rock-concerts, etc. :)

Answer (score 5):

I think generally these type of shots are referred to as "setup shots" or "behind the scenes" rather than backstage. Why exactly are you looking for them?

If you're looking for inspiration for DIY and amateur set ups I would add the following group to chills' list:

- [S.U.M. (Setups Mandatory)](http://www.flickr.com/groups/552101@N22/)

Which contains both the set up and the final shot which is quite helpful for working out how things are done.

If you're looking for something more "pro" then several photographers who are active on the net post really good behind the scenes videos, try:

- [Chase Jarvis Raw](http://blog.chasejarvis.com/blog/2007/05/chase-jarvis-raw-ninjas/)
- [Dave Hill behind the scenes](http://www.davehillphoto.com/bts/)

The F-Stop also regularly features set up shots and original images that are composited together, along with in depth interviews with the photographers/artists involved:

- [The F-Stop](http://www.thefstopmag.com/?p=33)

Comment: When you're not experienced enough it's rather better to take a look at setup shot to figure out which kind of light source was used and what it had produced in result. Sometimes it helps to understand that it's necessary to use, for example, bigger key light than you used in same setup or where to put kicker lights.

Answer (score 3):

The best place to look may very well be flickr.  You might be best off looking in group pools, for example:

- [Studio Lighting](http://www.flickr.com/groups/43292336@N00/pool/with/2471133513/)
- [Lighting and Posing Styles](http://www.flickr.com/groups/18233365@N00/pool/with/3808195326/)
- [Studios, locations, backstages and sets](http://www.flickr.com/groups/sets/)

Answer (score 1):

A great source, though not so very webby, is the series of articles Monte Zucker did for Shutterbug magazine over a number of years (certainly throughout the late '80s and '90s). There was rather a lot of detail about the setup, the whys and wherefores (complexion, clothing, tonal range, location constraints, that sort of thing). You may be able to find them archived in a local library, or if you know anyone who's been a shutterbug for a long enough time, they're likely to have something lying around.